# Chrome dev tools: How to calculate the total time required to load a popup and display it on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So I have a page and on the page I have an icon. On the click of the icon, a popup is loaded with data fetched via RESTful services.

I want to calculate the exact time it takes to fully display the popup from when the user clicked it.

I think we can do it using chrome dev tools, but the network tab in that just gives individual item load times. How do I get the total load time of all items in that?

I also used a chrome extension called page load time, but as the name suggests, it just gives me the total PAGE load time. I need the same for my popup, and I cannot isolate the popup as a new html page and test it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using angular-ui ? Your popup is a modal?

Comment: No unfortunately. My popup is just a separate html file that loads on the parent page. The internal code is however angular. So the entire popup is an angular app with a controller and stuff. The ajax request is angular as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it inside out.

You can't calculate how long request will be executed, since users has different internet speed, plus it's physical signal traveling via internet lines (so almost random time).

You have to use callback function that is called when request ends.

If using Ajax it would be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://restful.com/getItem',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data) {
         // Do something when you get response. "Data" contains server response.
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, to be more precise, I know that my ajax request gives me the results in around 300ms. I actually want to know, how much time does it take for my angular code to form that data in the desired format and display it. That includes loading my html, css, js, icons etc. Since they are all on my local dev env, I should be able to do it somehow?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani No, you will never know exact time.